# Cycle through class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cycle

I've got the html below, and I wish to auto-cycle through it. It's currently done manually with a onclick. But how can I get it to cycle? it basically just changes the class name on a wrapper div like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="client-relations-bg" class="background_tab1">
        ...content...
    </div>
</body>
```

I have the class image information here, in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab1{background: url('/media/2/background-image-1.png') no-repeat center top;}
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab2{background: url('/media/32/background-image-6.jpg') no-repeat center top;}
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab3{background: url('/media/17/background-image-3.jpg') no-repeat center top;}
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab4{background: url('/media/12/background-image-2.png') no-repeat center top;}
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab5{background: url('/media/22/background-image-4.jpg') no-repeat center top;}
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab6{background: url('/media/37/background-image-7.jpg') no-repeat center top;}
    #client-relations-bg.background_tab7{background: url('/media/2900/Header_image.jpg') no-repeat center top;}
</style>
```

So I need this: `class="background_tab1"` to cycle through `tab1` to `tab7`.

Comment: @CR41G14: that alone won't help solving the problem. Also it is definitely possible to do this without jQuery aswell, but maybe not so easy.

Comment: @Constantinius I was basically setting a platform for reasearch

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need to use jQuery

```
(function(){
    var interval = 1000;
    var currentBackgroundId = 1;
    window.setInterval(function(){
        currentBackgroundId++;
        if (currentBackgroundId == 8) currentBackgroundId = 1;

        var element = document.getElementById('client-relations-bg');
        element.className = 'background_tab' + currentBackgroundId;
    }, interval);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has really good class manipulation methods. All you need to do is either parse your current classes to look for the number at present, or store it in a global variable and do `i++ % 7` when setting the next one.

Answer (score 1):

if you know you class names beforehand, this will do:

```
var
  classList = ['background_tab1', 'background_tab2', 'background_tab3'],
  $el = $('#client-relations-bg');

(function next() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    classList.push(classList.shift());
    $el.removeClass().addClass(classList[0]);
    next();
  }, 2000);
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2uqp/

Comment: This works well thanks, how do you add a fade to that? .fadeIn / Out, but where do you put it? after the next().fadeIn(500) ?

Comment: you want to fade the background image?

Comment: I'm afraid, fading background images is not possible without additional markup and a lot of changes to the code above.

Comment: To be a bit more clear about this; It's not the problem of the code above, but rather a problem in all generality to fade background images, as there is no css property to use. One would have to use multiple elements stacked on top of each other and further stuff, which could get messy rather quickly. A usable fake would be to fade to a transition color (e.g. white/black) change the image and fade the color back out. But this would still need at least one additional element in the markup.

Comment: ok thanks, i just tried a fadeIn fadeOut and it fades everything inside the div as well, not just the image

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var classes = [
    "background_tab1",
    "background_tab2",
    "background_tab3",
    "background_tab4",
    "background_tab5",
    "background_tab6",
    "background_tab7"
];
setInterval(function() {
    var $div = $("#client-relations-bg");
    $.each(classes, function(i, c) {
        if ($div.hasClass(c)) {
            var j = (i + 1) % classes.length;
            $div.removeClass(c).addClass(classes[j]).text(classes[j]);
            return false;
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```

});​

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mWYF6/2/)

Comment: That's great works well, where would a fade go in that? after the .text(j).fade(500); ?

Comment: Can you explain the what fades in and what fades out?